Why is my multiport adapter not detecting my Ethernet port on Windows?
I am using Hiksemi multiport adapter for my Huawei MateBook. All the adapters are working well except ethernet port.
In fact, the lights are blinking in the Ethernet port of Hiksemi multiport adapter but I could not detect that in my laptop on Windows.


screenshots of the appropriate device manager tabs, and the 'old' style network control panel might be helpful here.
